# how to keep the user login for all pages in wordpress custom login function?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am using custom login function in  fuction.php for client area.But the problem is that user loges in   only for one page.If user goes to another page.He has to again  login and so on.

How can I keep the user login for all pages instead of one?

Also ,plz review my login function .if i am doing right?

PLZ HELP.

```
function login(){

     global $wpdb;

  if(isset($_POST['loggingg'])  AND  !empty($_POST['loggingg'])) {

    $email = $wpdb->escape ($_REQUEST['email']);
    $pass = $wpdb->escape ($_REQUEST['pass']);

    $sql = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_email='$email'");
    $numrows = $wpdb->num_rows;

    foreach ($sql as $fsql) {
        $password = $fsql->user_pass;
        $user_id = $fsql->ID;
        $username = $fsql->fname;
        $remember = $fsql->remember;

    }
    if($password) {
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data[] = $username;
        $login_data[] = $password;
        $login_data[] = $remember = TRUE;

        $wpdb->query ("UPDATE  wp_users  SET useronline='1' WHERE ID='$user_id'");

        $user_verify = wp_signon ($login_data, FALSE);
        wp_set_auth_cookie ($user_verify, 0, 0);


        wp_set_current_user ($user_id, $username);
        do_action ('wp_set_current_user');


    }
    else {
        echo "username r password is wrong.If you forgot ur password click <a href='#'>here</a>";
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Just store it in the session variable intead of using an sql field to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Jerska ,I tried it ,but it did not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp signon` function: [Function Reference/wp signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

as you can see here:

```
<?php wp_signon( $credentials, $secure_cookie ) ?>
```

it gets and array ($credentials) and a boolean (which is optional).

here you can see a sample code it's use:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'username';
$creds['user_password'] = 'password';
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
   echo $user->get_error_message();
```

this function is a core wp function, means that which means that when it's used, it will do everything the wordpress need it to do for it to work as it should.

next, you need to use [WordPress Cookies](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies).

in your case i have seen  you used: [Function Reference/wp set auth cookie](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie)
which is taking these parameters:

```
<?php wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, $remember, $secure ) ?>
```

`$user_id` is a integer and `$remember` is a boolean (true/false).

in the `$user_id` you tried to put a variable which is not an integer.
change it with `$user_verify->ID` and it should work.

Comment: Thank u,I tried it but still problem is there.when user  click any other page,He again has to sign in.

Comment: Are you polling the session when a page loads?

Answer (score 0):

I built a custom function for that for a similar project: http://cferdinandi.github.io/web-app-starter-kit/

It uses the built in login processes the WordPress uses, but from a custom page.